# "mute" command not working at all (Discord.py, rewrite)

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am currently making a bot for my Discord server and I wanted to add a 'mute' command, but it didnt work at all here's the code(I am using python 3.8.6)

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('Trial Moderator', 'Moderator', 'Administrator', 'Owner')
async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    muted_role = get(Guild.roles, id='760885845233631233')
    for role in member.roles:
        if role == muted_role:
            await ctx.send(f'{member} is already muted!')
            break
    member.add_roles(muted_role)
    await ctx.send(f'Muted {member}\nReason: {reason}')
```

There are no errors or anything when I run the command, and I am 100% sure that I have sufficient permissions, and when I run any other command they work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line:

```py
muted_role = get(Guild.roles, id='760885845233631233')
```

Your ID must be an interger, not a string. You also provided a blank `Guild` object so it can find any role:

```py
muted_role = get(ctx.guild.roles, id=760885845233631233)
```

You can also do a bit of refactoring:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('Trial Moderator', 'Moderator', 'Administrator', 'Owner')
async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    muted_role = get(ctx.guild.roles, id=760885845233631233)
    if muted_role in member.roles:
        await ctx.send(f'{member} is already muted!')
    else:
        member.add_roles(muted_role)
        await ctx.send(f'Muted {member}\nReason: {reason}')
```